# web.config redirecting folder name to file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, redirect

I hosted my site on windows server. I am trying to redirect user to a .html file inside web server when user browse sitename.com/foldername/

What tag should I add or modify in web.config file to achieve this. I used .htaccess file when I worked on linux hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must install url rewrite extension for iis,and then use this config in your webconfig file:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirecting to html file" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="sitename.com/foldername/" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="your html file address" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: any idea if  "url rewrite extension for iis" is by default installed for azure webapp?

Comment: go to this link for url rewrite in azure webapp..https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx